# Adding filed with select2 drop down not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Inside a form I have two fields (article and quantity) and I need to add that multiple times. This is a part of my form:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <table class="table table-bordered w-100" id="articles_table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>{{ __('smart.Name') }}</th>
                <th>{{ __('smart.Amount') }}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="article0">
                <td width="50%">
                    <select name="articles[]" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
                        <option></option>
                        @foreach (\Smart\Models\Warehouse\Article::all() as $article)
                            <option value="{{ $article->id }}">
                                {{ $article->name }}
                            </option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td width="50%">
                    <input type="number" name="quantities[]" class="form-control">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="article1"></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="row mt-2">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button id="add_row" class="btn btn-secondary float-right"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> {{ __('smart.Article') }}</button>
            <button id='delete_row' class="btn btn-danger float-left"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i> {{ __('smart.Article') }}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is mine js part

```
var row_number = 1;
$("#add_row").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var new_row_number = row_number - 1;
    $('#article' + row_number).html($('#article' + new_row_number).html()).find('td:first-child');
    $('#articles_table').append('<tr id="article' + (row_number + 1) + '"></tr>');
    row_number++;
});

$("#delete_row").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(row_number > 1){
        $("#article" + (row_number - 1)).html('');
        row_number--;
    }
});
```

but I have a problem after adding new row I can select anything (dropdown doesn't work).

I follow this [approach](https://quickadminpanel.com/blog/master-detail-form-in-laravel-jquery-create-order-with-products/)

Comment: if you dynamiclly appedn select2 , then on append you have to remove select to and re aasign select2

Comment: You mean something like select2('destroy') and then select2 on new added selector?

Comment: yes right that way

Comment: I try to find new select like this var articles = $('#article' + row_number).find('select'); and after that I use articles.select2('destroy'); and articles.select2(); but that is not working